# How to find leverage for futures

Tags: calculation, futures, leverage

In my understanding, leverage is the risk we take for our investment. That is highly leveraged instruments have high risk and high potential reward. But how can we calculate leverage of futures?

```
Instrument  Price   Lot Size    Margin
A            5.2    1000        1000
B            5.5    800         2000
C            10.3   250         1000
D            5.6    800         1010
E            100    10          500
```

How to calculate leverage of futures?

EDITED
@dg99 has already cleared my doubts but for more clarity I will add more information to this question.

I consider myself as a risk averse person and I would like to avoid highly leveraged instruments because of its high risk. Lets say I have an account balance of 1000 and I want to invest it in an instruments; according to the table we have three instruments to invest(A,C and E). To avoid risk I want to avoid highly leveraged instruments so in A.C and E I want to find which has the highest and lowest leverage.

Comment: This will help http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/leverage.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage (in the financial sense) is not necessarily a measurement of risk.  It's a mathematical definition: the value of your market position divided by the amount of principal you contributed toward the purchase of that position.  The definition is the same whether you're trading futures or any other type of financial instrument, but it is far more common for traders to use leverage on derivatives (futures, options, etc.) than on real assets (stocks, bonds, etc.).

In your example, assuming `margin` is the amount of money you borrowed and `price` is the amount you paid per lot, then the value of your Instrument A position is 5200, and you borrowed 1000 to buy it.  That means your principal investment was 4200, so your leverage is 5200/4200 = 1.238.

How is this number useful?  Imagine the price of Instrument A goes up 10% to 5.72.  You sell your position for 5720.  After paying 1000 (plus interest) back to your lender, you have 4720.  What was your percentage gain on this trade?

```
4720 / 4200 - 1 = .1238 = 12.38% (minus interest)
```

You realized a 12.38% gain when the price of Instrument A (or, equivalently, the value of your position in Instrument A) increased by only 10%.  Your leverage (1.238) tells you how much additional change you will see in the value of your *profit* for a given movement in the value of your *position*.

If you had not had a lender to loan you 1000, your 4200 principal would have only bought ~808 lots, which you would have sold for 4620.  Then your percentage gain would have been:

```
4620 / 4200 - 1 = .10 = 10%
```

Without leverage your percentage gain in profit is exactly equal to the percentage gain in the value of your position (minus transaction fees).

But watch out because the same thing happens on the downside!  If Instrument A had decreased 10% in value instead (and you sold it), you would have lost:

```
5200 * 0.9 = 4680
4680 - 1000 = 3680
3680 / 4200 - 1 = -.1238 = -12.38% (minus interest)
```

So your loss is also multiplied by your leverage.

This is why some people equate leverage with risk: each movement in price is magnified (maybe extremely) by your leverage.  But leverage is not *inherently* risky; being leveraged in a predictably stable instrument is a lot less risky than owning an unstable instrument outright.  (Of course, there's not much point in leveraging a stable asset, so nobody does it.)